# Opening and running a python script in spyder from tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I was hoping there is a way to open a '.py' file in Spyder and run it in a correlating IPython Console from a Tkinter window.
I have been able to get scripts to run using threading and os.system, but I would really like to run from Spyder in IPython

Here is the code I wrote, run1 works, but does not open spyder to run it.
I would like to know if something exists like run2. (I know that run_in_spyder is not a function). Perhaps there is some CMD commands for Spyder that I do not know of.

to_run is just an example script.

Here is the backbone of my code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from collections import OrderedDict
import os, sys
from shutil import copy

from threading import Thread
from to_run import make_df

root_dir = os.getcwd()+os.sep

class LipPy_UI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('450x300+200+200')
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use('vista')
        self.title = master.title('Title')
        self.labelText = tk.StringVar()
        self.labelText.set('Welcome. \n From here you can do all kinds of stuff and things!')
        self.introText = tk.Label(self.master, textvariable=self.labelText, height =4)
        self.introText.pack()
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Run', width = 25, command = self.run)
        self.button1.pack(padx=15,pady=10)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = 0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = 'Quit', command = self.close_window)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = 'File',menu = self.filemenu)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.frame.pack()

    def run1(self):
        thread1 = Thread(target = make_df)
        thread1.start()

    def run2(self):
        file_to_run = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        desired_working_dir = 'D:\My_Scripts'
        run_in_spyder(runfile(file_to_run, wdir=desired_working_dir))

    def close_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if '__main__' == __name__:
    root = tk.Tk()
    LipPy_UI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```